# Is it possible to use messaging, and kafka-messaging separately from helidon?

Tags: helidon

I created library using helidon-messaging, helidon-messaging-kafka. Also I created an example Java SE app using that library and all works fine. But when I try to use that library in Java EE (Weblogic) legacy application I have got an exception while that application starts:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Config with qualifiers @Default 
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject io.helidon.messaging.connectors.kafka.KafkaConnector(Config)   
  at io.helidon.messaging.connectors.kafka.KafkaConnector.<init>(KafkaConnector.java:0)
```

Is it possible some how to switch off CDI stuff there?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to exclude the connector package from bean scanning?

Something like this should help:

```xml
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
       version="2.0"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">

     <scan>
        <exclude name="io.helidon.messaging.connectors.kafka.**" />
     </scan>
</beans>
```

More info can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#exclude_filters)